# Почему не показывает ProgressDialog после вызова SystemClock.sleep?

Tags: java, android

Я хочу потестировать как работает ProgressDialog` и пишу такой простой код:

```
package com.example.aleksey.test;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void click(View view) {
    showProgressDialog();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        SystemClock.sleep(100);
    }
    hideProgressDialog();
}

private void showProgressDialog() {
    if (dialog == null) {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.saving));
        dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    }
    dialog.show();
}

private void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
        dialog.hide();
    }
}
}
```

Функция `SystemClock.sleep()` отрабатывает, но почему тогда не отображает `ProgressDialog`? что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что вы запускаете показ диалога, затем слипаете основной поток, в котором весь UI и работает, и затем запускаете скрытие диалога. В результате UI замораживается не успев ничего отобразить, а при разморозке уже надо прятать сразу, а показать то так и не успели.

В общем вот так Вам надо:

```
package com.example.aleksey.test;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void click(View view) {
        showProgressDialog();
        view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                hideProgressDialog();
            }
        }, 1000);
    }

    private void showProgressDialog() {
        if (dialog == null) {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            dialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.saving));
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        }
        dialog.show();
    }

    private void hideProgressDialog() {
        if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.hide();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Разобрался